# Sequential Searching with a Geometric Series

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Hi I am having the following probability problem and can not figure out how to tackle it.

Suppose a consumer aiming to buy 1 unit of a product searches sequentially over stores who offer prices  = 1,2,3,...,  with probabilities 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ... 1/2^n . He has to pay search costs of 1 for every store he visits. My question is, when does he stop to search and at what price does he stop to search?

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  Note that your header doesn't appear to match the question in the body of your post.

Comment: What title would you suggest?

Comment: As I can't sort out what you are asking, I have no recommendation as to the title.  I suggest editing for clarity.

Comment: Edited it, I hope its better now.

Comment: I don't understand what makes the fellow stop searching.  One guess might be "stop when the expected value of the next toss is higher than what he currently can pay".  But you might mean something else.

Comment: For instance:  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n+1}{2^n}=3$, so one thought would be to stop when you currently have the option of paying $≤3$, and toss again otherwise.  Is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I dont get the intuition. Could you explain a bit more how you came up with this?

Comment: Why does this sum equal 3? How does it connect to the search costs? Why do I accept if price is below three?

Comment: How would this solution change if we would have search costs of 2? Your reasoning is correct. He stops if the costs of an additional search is higher than the expected benefit.

Comment: Again, I am just guessing as to what you are asking.  The sum I wrote is a routine variant of the standard Geometric Series, it represents the expected cost if you only could do one search.  I'll post a different approach (which is possibly closer to what you want) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your strategy here will be to fix a threshold $N$ and stop whenever you get $≤N$.  To be sure, there are other possible strategies (time dependent or total cost dependent) but let's stick with this family of strategies.  Given $N$, let $E_N$ be your expected total cost if you follow this strategy.  We'll find $N$ for which $E_N$ is minimal.

Case:  $N=1$.  Consider the first toss.  If you see a $1$ you stop and pay $2$.  Otherwise you repeat, but your expected cost is now $E_N+1$ since you will have spent $1$ already.  Thus $$E_1=2\times \frac 12+(E_1+1)\times \frac 12\implies E_1= 3$$

Case:  $N=2$  By the same argument we have $$E_2=2\times \frac 12+3\times \frac 14+(E_2+1)\times \frac 14\implies E_2=\frac 83$$

So taking $N=2$ is better.

Case:  $N=3$  We get
$$E_3=2\times \frac 12+3\times \frac 14+ 4\times \frac 18 +(E_3+1)\times \left(1-\frac 12-\frac 14-\frac 18\right)\implies E_2=\frac {19}7$$

which is slightly better than $N=2$

Case:  $N=4$  We get
$$E_4=2\times \frac 12+3\times \frac 14+ 4\times \frac 18 + 5\times \frac 1{16} +(E_4+1)\times \left(1-\frac 12-\frac 14-\frac 18-\frac 1{16}\right)\implies E_4=\frac {14}5$$

which is quite a bit worse .  Taking larger $N$ just makes things worse (as the fixed initial terms sum to more than $E_3$ on their own), so $N=3$ is the optimal strategy.

You should easily be able to adopt this argument to the case where the fixed search cost is $2$ (or whatever) instead of $1$.  Clearly, if the fixed cost is high, you will be highly motivated to take whatever you see first so the threshold will climb.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly (!) what I am looking for. Now I understand the intuition and the reasoning :)